# Arrange data using loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops

If I have:

```
  t=(1:1:5)'
  time=1:3:100
```

How do I arrange data t in each column starting from 1 until the end, with an interval of 3. Which means that the data t (1 to 5) at column 1,4,7 and so on.

I've tried:

```
t=[1:1:5];
nt=length(temp);
time=[1:1:100];
nti=length(time);
x=zeros(nt,nti);

temp=temp';
initiator=2;
monomer=3;

post=1:3:100;

for l=1:post

step=1;
maxstep=100;
 while (step<maxstep)
    step=step+3;
    temp=(1:1:5)';
 end
t(:,l)=t;
x=[t];

end
```

This only shows result X with temp at column 1. I do not know how to to arrange this data at columns that I want.

Hope someone will help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How many dimensions does your data have? If you already have "temp" (temperature?) and "time" as your first two dimensions and you want "t" to be the third dimension, then create a three-dimension matrix.

To extract from indexes [1 4 7 10 13 16 ... ], use `(1:3:end)`
To extract from indexed [2 5 8 11 14 17 ... ], use `(2:3:end)`

In MATLAB's colon notation, the first value is the start. Second value is increment. Third value is the end value and is inclusive.

Comment: ops,sorry.i forgot to change.temp i change to t.means that length(temp) is length (t).what i want is the result will appear like: 1st row [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ........                                                                              2nd row  2 0 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 .........                                  3rd row  3 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 ...........                          4th row  4 0 0 4 0 0 4 0 0 4 0 0 ...........                            5th row  5 0 0 5 0 0 5 0 0 5 0 0]